# How do I hide columns in SSRS with TWO conditions?

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a report with a ColumnA that needs to be hidden if to specific values for parameters are met.

```
Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)=True
```

and

```
Parameters!vType.Value = 1
```

I've tried

```
= Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)=True and Parameters!vType.Value = 1

= iif(Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)=True and Parameters!vType.Value = 1, true, false)
```

and it doesn't produce an error, yet one condition is always ignored.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of parameter is vType? Is it multi-value? BTW: You probably don;t need the `=True` part on your first expression as `Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)` will return a boolean anyway.

Comment: vType is an int without multi-values - thank you so much you're saving my butt today :D

Comment: No problem..although I'm not sure why `= Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0) and Parameters!vType.Value = 1` would not work then. I suggest you add two text boxes somewhere on your report to show each part of the expression. One showing `= Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)` expression and  one showing `=Parameters!vType.Value = 1`. If this does not help, edit your question and show your exact parameter setup and I will try to replicate.